# Let $H$ act on $G$ by right multiplication. $\displaystyle g_1 \in O_{g_2} \iff g_2^{-1} g_1\in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please note, my question is not to prove the theorem in the title but rather about what my professor said regarding the theorem.

I am listening online to a lecture by my professor; the audio is good but the video not so much so I can't see parts of the board very well. The professor first defined the equivalence relation $g_1 R g_2 \iff g_2 = h \cdot g_1$ for some $h \in H$ (the dot is used for the group action; we use no symbol for multiplication in the group). Then he wrote the following theorem on the board

> Let $H$ act on $G$ by right multiplication. Then $\displaystyle g_1 R g_2 \iff g_2^{-1} g_1\in H$

Then he said and wrote (as far as I could read):

> Before we prove this, I will show you the way which I like to remember the theorem. We have to be careful though.The left coset of $g_1$ is written as $g_1 H$ [red flad in my mind; I thought it was $H g_1$ because left coset is right multiplication]. If $g_1$ and $g_2$ are in the same orbit, then it should be that $g_1 H = g_2 H$. Then "multiplying" by $g_2^{-1}$ on the left, we get $g_2^{-1}g_1H=H$. So  $g_2^{-1}g_1$ would have to be in $H$.

So he got the "right" answer to remember ($g_2^{-1}g_1$ as opposed to  $g_1^{-1}g_2$ or something of the like) by writing the right coset instead of the left coset. Now I would be fine with this, because it's supposed to be just a way to remember, not a proof. But my professor made no explicit mention that he is writing to cosets backwards. This leads me to believe that I am missing something. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you say that $g_1 H$ is a right coset? Maybe the convention varies, but I've always seen this called a left coset (should be "left coset of $H$ containing $g_1$", though; I don't think "left coset of $g_1$" makes any sense).

Comment: @Bungo I think I see my problem; I knew that right multiplication means $h \cdot g = gh$, but when we wrote it with sets I confused myself and thought it was $Hg$, that is $g$  doing the multiplication on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is acting on $G$ by right multiplication, the orbit of $g_1$ is $g_1H$, the left coset of $H$ by $g_1$. To be more precise 
$$O_g=\{h\cdot g : h\in H\}= \{gh^{-1} : h\in H\} = \{gh:h\in H\}= gH. $$
Then the rest of the argument seems fairly clear. If anything is still confusing you, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I see my problem; I knew that right multiplication means $h \cdot g = gh$, but when we wrote it with sets I confused myself and thought it was $Hg$, that is $g$  doing the multiplication on the right.

Comment: Ah there you go. Glad to have helped. Though actually, if $H$ is acting on the left by right multiplication, it should be, $h\cdot g = gh^{-1}$. Otherwise $h_1 \cdot (h_2 \cdot g))=h_1\cdot (gh_2) = g h_2 h_1 \ne g h_1 h_2 = (h_1h_2)\cdot g$. That is, if you don't have the inverses, right multiplication by $H$ doesn't satisfy the axioms for a left action. With the inverses, we have $h_1 \cdot (h_2 \cdot g))=h_1\cdot (gh_2^{-1}) = g h_2^{-1} h_1^{-1} = g (h_1 h_2)^{-1} = (h_1h_2)\cdot g$.

Comment: Woah thanks I never realized that; I don't remember the professor taking this into account in the proof. I will have to look into it.

Comment: @Ovi Some group theorists apply group actions (and mappings in general) on the right, in which case they would write the result of $h$ acting on $g$ as $g \cdot h$. With that convention, $g \cdot h = gh$ would be a valid action.

Comment: @Bungo Hmm yeah I will just have to go back to the lectures and look into it.